# How to compile FFmpeg for arm64e - clang is unable to create an executable file

Tags: xcode, shell, ffmpeg

We are using FFmpeg in our Xcode/Swift project. Compiling and running the app with arm64 architecture works well. Now we want to support devices with A12Z chip. They have the architecture "arm64e".
We are using the [build script from kewlbear](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) and modified the line `ARCHS="arm64 armv7 x86_64 i386"` to `ARCHS="arm64e arm64 armv7 x86_64 i386"`.
When we run the script, we get an error `clang is unable to create an executable file` at the beginning of the build for arm64e.
How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, please read the second sentence..

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue, and after checked, I found the parameter "--cpu" is incorrect for arm64. The original is "--cpu=arm64-v8a". The correct one is "--cpu=armv8-a". The "--cpu" parameter must be start with "armv", you can find the clue in the FFMPEG configure file like below:

```
case $cpu in
    armv*)
        cpuflags="-march=$cpu"
        subarch=$(echo $cpu | sed 's/[^a-z0-9]//g')
    ;;
    *)
        cpuflags="-mcpu=$cpu"
        case $cpu in
            cortex-a*)                               subarch=armv7a  ;;
            cortex-r*)                               subarch=armv7r  ;;
            cortex-m*)                 enable thumb; subarch=armv7m  ;;
            arm11*)                                  subarch=armv6   ;;
            arm[79]*e*|arm9[24]6*|arm96*|arm102[26]) subarch=armv5te ;;
            armv4*|arm7*|arm9[24]*)                  subarch=armv4   ;;
            *)                             subarch=$(probe_arm_arch) ;;
        esac
    ;;
esac
```

And below is my scrip, which can work well.

```
#!/bin/bash

TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/
API=21


function build_android
{
echo "Compiling FFmpeg for $CPU"
./configure \
    --disable-x86asm \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --disable-static \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-small \
    --enable-gpl \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-programs \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --target-os=android \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
    --arch=$ARCH \
    --cpu=$CPU \
    --cc=$CC

make clean
make -j32
make install
echo "The Compilation of FFmpeg for $CPU is completed"
}

#armv8-a
ARCH=arm64
CPU=armv8-a
CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android$API-clang
CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android$API-clang++
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
build_android

# armv8a -> arm64 -> aarch64-linux-android-
# armv7a -> arm -> arm-linux-androideabi-
# x86 -> x86 -> i686-linux-android-
# x86_64 -> x86_64 -> x86_64-linux-android-

#armv7-a
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv7-a
CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi$API-clang
CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi$API-clang++
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
build_android
```

Comment: Where do I have to change this? In the build script I don't found anything like this. Does it work with your change on an a12z chip device?

Comment: Hi, I have attached my script above, which can work well on arm and arm64. You can refer it. And please pay attention to the parameter "CPU", which should start with "armv*".

Comment: @nick, I followed your code but getting same error. using ndk r26 , error says :  ndk_r26b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabiclang is unable to create an executable file.  It will be great if you can help :)